# Selenium selecting a different element with the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to use find element by css selector so that everytime selenium completes the task on one element it moves onto the next element with the same class to do the same?

For while example using this line of code the bot repeats the task on the same element.

```
 comment_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("svg[aria-label='Comment']")
 comment_button.click()
 
 comment_box = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[aria-label='Add a comment…']")
 comment_box.send_keys("xxx")

 post_button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
 post_button.click()

 driver.back()
```

How can I make sure that every time the task is completed selenium moves on to the next button?

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your question ? Like what is HTML DOM for your element (S) you want to interact with ? What is the exact steps you want to perform on them ? Do you want to iterate through all elements present identified with a common locator ? Please be more specific so that we can provide a workable solution.

Comment: The element I need to interact has a DOM like this 

`<article><div><section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment">`

I just need to click this svg and I want the bot to click only once for every element in the page with this aria-label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Egco Based on you comment what i understood is:

1. You want to locate all elements with DOM as
2. Once its found you want to click on it.
3. I assume page in not refreshing once you click on this element.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rahul/OneDrive/Desktop/abc.html")
driver.maximize_window()
comment_button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("svg[aria-label='add comment']")
for btn in comment_button :
    btn.click()
```

Please let me know if it works . Also let me know if i did not understand your question completely.

**Dummy HTML:**

```
<article>
<div>
<section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment"></svg></section></span></button>
</div>
<div>
<section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment"></svg></section></span></button>
</div>
<div>
<section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment"></svg></section></span></button>
</div>
<div>
<section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment"></svg></section></span></button>
</div>
<div>
<section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment"></svg></section></span></button>
</div>
<div>
<section><span><button><div><svg aria-label="add comment"></svg></section></span></button>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: I have already tried a similar method in my code however using this method selenium keeps clicking on the same element. For example if the page has 10 elements with css selector `<svg aria-label="add comment">` selenium doesn't click all 10 in that page but it only selects the closest one to the top of the page and clicks on that one element repeatedly.

Comment: I am not sure, but i have tried same code by creating a dummy html file and it clicks all 6 buttons (As i kept 6 divs in my html file) . Please see edited answer.

Comment: I hope you are using find_elements_by_css_selector instead of find_element_by_css_selector

Comment: Thank you so much I didnt know there was a difference between writing elements and element this solved my problem

Comment: Happy to help :) I believe it will help others as well as me if you up vote , if it solves your issue.